# How to avoid coloring over specific colors in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that imports various black and white pictures, and would like to have it so that the stroke does not color over the black pixels. Right now, the brush effect is done with:

```
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ...
    ctx.beginPath();
    //xy being the mouse coordinates, retrieved earlier. 
    ctx.arc(xy[0], xy[1], ctx.lineWidth/2, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
```

Here is an example of the effect I would like to achieve.

[image: Depiction of desired effect]

Comment: If you change your "black and white" pictures to "black and transparent" then you could just overlay the image on top of the canvas

Comment: @musefan The images are user supplied, is there a way I can do that programmatically?

Comment: Please give information on why and in which cases you would want to achieve this effect, and possibly of what resolution/complexity the user defined pictures are.

Comment: Whenever I would make a stroke that would cover black pixels, I would instead like to stroke everything except the black pixels. Resolution and complexity can be of any valid theoretical values, so long as black pixels are left alone when color is laid down.

Comment: @VinKing: Yes, you could quite easily convert an image to make everything transparent except the black pixels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[ Update given new info by questioner ]**

Canvas does not yet support color blending, so you can achieve your effect using `getImageData`

context.getImageData gets an array representing the red, green, blue & alpha values of every pixel on the canvas.

You can use these pixel arrays to replace the white pixels on the image with the stroke pixel above.

- get the pixel array of the stroke
- get the pixel array of the image
- Compare every stroke pixel with every image pixel
- If the stroke is over a white pixel, replace the white pixel with the stroke-color pixel

[image]

**Notes:**

Black & White images are most often grayscale and not actually pure black and white.  To replace "whiteish" pixels you must test the image pixels for a wider range of rgb combinations.  Whiteish pixels tend to have a higher sum of the rgb color values so you can test if r+b+g >600 (or your desired "whiteish" cutoff value).

To use `getImageData` the images drawn on the canvas must originate on the same domain as the web page or else getImageData will fail with a security violation.  This might require you to upload the users images to your server and deliver it back to the web page.  Alternatively, you can use FileReader on the clients that support it to let the user load an image from their local file system to the web page.

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/26N7S/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var imgDataImage,imgDataStroke,dataImage,dataStroke;

    var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/BW.gif";
    function start(){

        canvas.width=img.width+100;
        canvas.height=img.height+100;

        drawStroke(ctx);
        imgDataStroke=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        dataStroke=imgDataStroke.data;

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        drawImage();
        imgDataImage=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        dataImage=imgDataImage.data;

        for(var i=0;i<dataStroke.length;i+=4){

            if(dataStroke[i+3]<200){
                // not under stroke, no changes to image
            }else if(dataImage[i+3]<200){
                // is under stroke, but not over image
                // so replace the image pixel with the color of the stroke
                dataImage[i+0]=dataStroke[i+0];
                dataImage[i+1]=dataStroke[i+1];
                dataImage[i+2]=dataStroke[i+2];
                dataImage[i+3]=dataStroke[i+3];
            }else if(dataImage[i]+dataImage[i+1]+dataImage[i+2]>150){
                // this image pixel is under the stroke and is "blackish", 
                // so replace the image pixel with the color of the stroke
                dataImage[i+0]=dataStroke[i+0];
                dataImage[i+1]=dataStroke[i+1];
                dataImage[i+2]=dataStroke[i+2];
                dataImage[i+3]=dataStroke[i+3];
            }else{
                // the pixel is under the stroke but is not "blackish",
                // so no changes to image
            }

        }

        ctx.putImageData(imgDataImage,0,0);
    }

    function drawImage(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,50,50);
    }

    function drawStroke(ctx){
        ctx.lineCap="round";
        ctx.lineWidth=15;
        ctx.strokeStyle="lightcoral";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(75,25);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width-75,canvas.height-25);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The black rectangle is representative of how I would like to retain any black pixels on the canvas during a stroke, not representative of a black rectangle.

Comment: I've updated my answer... Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks for this, this gave me exactly what I needed once I integrated your solution. Works fantastically for my needs.